# Efficient way to replace specific color in Bitmap/Image

Tags: c#, .net, image, image-processing, bitmap

In my grayscale picture I need to find specific value and replace it with some color, e.g yellow. Here is the code which I have right now, but it's not as fast as I need. Is there any more efficient way to achieve that? I've red about the [ColorMatrix](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.imaging.colormatrix%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) Class, but couldn't find the way to replace the single value without to affect the whole image.

```
unsafe
{
    byte stlThres = 115;

    int bytePerPixel = Image.GetPixelFormatSize(kpImageViewer1.Image.PixelFormat) / 8;
    var data = kpImageViewer1.Image.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0, kpImageViewer1.Image.Width, kpImageViewer1.Image.Height), ImageLockMode.WriteOnly, kpImageViewer1.Image.PixelFormat);
    for (int y = 0; y < data.Height; y++)
    {
        byte* row = (byte*)data.Scan0 + (y * data.Stride);

        for (int x = 0; x < data.Width; x++, row += bytePerPixel)
        {
            if (row[0] == stlThres)
            {
                row[0] = 0; //b
                row[1] = 255; //g
                row[2] = 255; //r
                if (bytePerPixel == 4)
                {
                    row[3] = 255; //a
                }
            }
        }
    }
    kpImageViewer1.Image.UnlockBits(data);
}
```

Comment: You could try BitBlt.  [Here's](http://www.vbaccelerator.com/home/VB/Tips/Replace_One_Colour_With_Another_in_a_Picture/article.asp) a VB example.

Comment: Very minor tweaks might be moving your `data.Scan0`, `data.Width`, `data.Stride`, and the `BytePerPixel == 4` check outside the loops altogether since they're effectively constants for the duration of the loops (the last of which would mean you'd have to duplicate the basic loop structure). It might provide a minor (but plausibly _measurable_ improvement depending on the frequency this is called and the size of the bitmap)

Comment: add image of your result and actual result

Answer (score 1):

In the case of a 4 channel image, where each pixel is 4 bytes (8-bits per channel), you can use a 256 entry lookup-table indexed by `row[0]` and assign all four channels simultaneously as a single 32-bit `int`.

Comment: good point, but 4 channel image is a very rare case, I've added this check just for compatibility. So I'm missing Int24 type now :D

Comment: In the case of a 3 channel image, you might try to process 4 pixels simultaneously and with some bit-masks treat them as 3 `int`s.

Comment: could you please give an example?

Comment: I'm not sure it's really worth the effort. Just remove the 4-channel test outside the loop and keep the loops tight.