# Bitmap constructor with scan0 and unmanaged resources

Tags: c#, .net, bitmap, garbage-collection

I have written some code to retrieve frames from a camera, along with information obtained from these frames, and to display them on a form.
All the data that I get is unmanaged as it comes form a library of my own written in c++ and working with OpenCv.
I prefer getting all the data at once with a single function call and not using a wrapper to OpenCv that would PInvoke several times to get the same result. Furthermore for me the code is easier to maintain and I have much more control on everything that is going on and I have many other reason to prefer this approach.
Everything is ok, (seemingly) perfectly working and I’m happy, but… there is something I would like to understand better with your help.

At a certain point I create a bitmap with the unmanaged pixel data with the method

```
public Bitmap(int width,int height,int stride,PixelFormat format, IntPtr scan0);
```

My question are the following (I have some idea, but just tell me if I’m right) :

1) I don’t release the data pointed by scan0 as I think that, once the data is owned by the bitmap object, it will do the job for me via its Garbage Collection. Am I right?

2) I don’t like the fact that a new instance of bitmap is created and allocated every time (apart from the pixel data), but I suppose that there is no better way of getting a Bitmap out of unmanaged data.

3) I think that there is no need to tell the Garbage Collector that there is a big amount of data to clean up with GC.AddMemoryPressure(…) as it knows it, estimating from the information provided with the initialization.

**EDIT**
I've found on the documentation

> The caller is responsible for allocating and freeing the block of memory specified by the scan0 parameter. However, the memory should not be released until the related Bitmap is released.

The only way to do this is that the Bitmap object created in such a way leaves the data untouched and doesn't change its position in memory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1) I don’t release the data pointed by scan0 as I think that, once the
>   data is owned by the bitmap object, it will do the job for me via its
>   Garbage Collection. Am I right?

No, the garbage collector knows nothing about the object, which you've initialized on the unmanaged side, that is why it is unmanaged. So you have to call delete in the unmanaged code to release the allocated memory.

> 2) I don’t like the fact that a new instance of bitmap is created and
>   allocated every time (apart from the pixel data), but I suppose that
>   there is no better way of getting a Bitmap out of unmanaged data.

There is a way and a keyword is [unsafe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/chfa2zb8.aspx). You can run the c++ code inside of the unsafe block, but you must allow this in the c# project settings. So you can reuse every pixel of once initialized bitmap

```
unsafe
{
    byte stlThres = 115;
    Bitmap myBmp = ...; // init the bitmap 
    var data = myBmp.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0, myBmp.Width, myBmp.Height), ImageLockMode.WriteOnly, myBmp.PixelFormat);
    for (int y = 0; y < data.Height; y++)
    {
        byte* row = (byte*)data.Scan0 + (y * data.Stride);
        //...
}
```

> 3) I think that there is no need to tell the Garbage Collector that
>   there is a big amount of data to clean up with GC.AddMemoryPressure(…)
>   as it knows it, estimating from the information provided with the
>   initialization.

If you created a managed Bitmap object (with new), it will be released automatically after it gets out of scope or will not be referenced any longer.

Comment: Thank for your answer
1. Ok. In my case I think I will release the unmanaged buffer just at the end of the process, because it points always to the same data on top of which a new frame is copied.
2. I wonder if the overhead associated with this loop is less than the one determined by allocation/deallocation of resources. And if the former is true if anyway it is negligible.
3. I could dispose it explicitly of letting the GC do the job. Probably this second option is preferable.

Comment: I don't really know why you use c# and want to keep control about everything. This is an advantage of the c# that you do not need to worry about many things, e.g. memory management and it is still very efficient. Maybe you should stay in the unmanaged world? I guess you want to look at c++/cli.

Comment: Because I feel comfortable with c#, when I have not to worry about memory issues, and at the same time with OpenCv. The only contact between the two should be this retrieving of data. Once I’ve done it and I’m sure it is ok, I could use both of them the way I’ve always done. I think I’ve almost finished, just want to be sure of the last details. Furthermore I think than when your application is performance demanding you have always to ask yourself what is going on under the hood.

Comment: @GiuseppeDini agree, I've asked a similar question about this topic some time ago http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15386385/